# How can I prompt user what data to copy from CSV to XLS using Python?

Tags: python, csv, xls

I would like to ask if it's possible in Python which would open the `CSV` or `XLS` file and prompts the user to input a specific row (from and to) and copy paste that information to another `CSV` or `XLS` file. To help visualize it here is an example:

**XLS File1 (Source)**

| Bin_Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| B |  |
| C |  |
| D |  |
| E |  |
| F |  |
| G |  |
| H |  |
| I |  |
| J |  |

**CSV File1 (Source)**

| Bin_Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 22 |
| B | 24 |
| C | 45 |
| D | 65 |
| E | 76 |
| F | 23 |
| G | 12 |
| H | 23 |
| I | 51 |
| J | 61 |

So the idea is, having these 2 files, user will be asked to input a row range based on `Bin_Name` from `CSV File1` and put the `Quantity` data to `XLS File1`'s `Quantity` column.

Example: The script will ask user to input row 1 - 5 from `CSV File1` and automatically copies that data to `XLS File1`. Thank you very much in advance. Appreciate all your help.

**XLS File1 (Expected Result)**

| Bin_Name | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| A | 22 |
| B | 24 |
| C | 45 |
| D | 65 |
| E | 76 |
| F |  |
| G |  |
| H |  |
| I |  |
| J |  |

Comment: You could certainly have a command line parameter like `python copycsv.py A-E`.  That would be easy to parse and prepare.

Comment: There is no way I know that allows inserting/replacing data in the middle of the file. You'll need to read an original file, make modifications and write data with changes to a new file, or overwrite the original. You can have a universal data structure and you can use that data structure to generate csv and xls. When you want to change data in files you can read data from one of those files to this universal data structure using xls or csv reader - you will need to implement readers. And when you finish making changes you can save data to csv and xls files by overwriting the original ones.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your inputs. Appreciate it!